# Transforming wide data to long format with multiple variables

Tags: r, transformation

this may have a simple answer but after after a few hours of searching I still cannot find it. Basically I need to turn a wide dataset to a long format dataset but with multiple variables. My dataset structure looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                  sex = c("M","F","M"),
                  day0s = c(21,25,15),
                  day1s = c(20,30,18),
                  day2s = c(18,18,17),
                  day0t = c(2,5,7),
                  day1t = c(3,6,5),
                  day2t = c(3,8,7))
df1
 id sex day0s  day1s  day2s day0t  day1t  day2t
 1   M    21     20     18     2      3      3
 2   F    25     30     18     5      6      8
 3   M    15     18     17     7      5      7
```

Basically 3 subjects have done a math test (s) and history test (t) every day for 3 days.
I tried to use gather from tidyr to turn it into long form, but I don't know how to assign the mt and ht variables to the same day. I also coded a new variable day with just day0 = 0, day1 = 1 and day2 = 2.

```
dfl ＜- df1 %＞%
  gather(day, value, - c(id,sex))
dfl
id sex  variable value  day
1   M   day0s     21    0
1   M   day1s     20    1
1   M   day2s     18    2
1   M   day0t      2    0
1   M   day1t      3    1
1   M   day2t      3    2
2   F   day0s     25    0
2   F   day1s     30    1
2   F   day2s     18    2
2   F   day0t      5    0
2   F   day1t      6    1
2   F   day2t      8    2
3   M   day0s     15    0
3   M   day1s     18    1
3   M   day2s     17    2
3   M   day0t      7    0
3   M   day1t      5    1
3   M   day2t      7    1
```

Ideally in the end it should look like this.

```
id sex   day   s     t
1   M     0    21    2
1   M     1    20    3
1   M     2    18    3
2   F     0    25    5
2   F     1    30    6
2   F     2    18    8
3   M     0    15    7
3   M     1    18    5
3   M     2    17    7
```

Do you please have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: I'd suggest removing the day and number suffix of the variable column. And then use pivot_wider to create the mt and ht columns.

Comment: The posted data has columns `day` with suffixes `s` and `t`, *not* `mt` and `ht`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use {tidyr}'s [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) here.

If your actual variables are named a bit differently, you can adapt the regex to your case. [Here](https://regex101.com/r/9P1nqc/1) you can try out and adapt accordingly . (Note that in R the backslash has to be escaped, therefore the
double backslash in `\\d+` and `\\w+`)

In general, the `names_pattern` argument works by matching the regex within the parenthesis with the `names_to` argument, so that here:

- `(\\d+)` -> becomes variable day. Regex `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.
- `(\\w+)` -> becomes ".value". Regex `\w+` matches 1 or more word character. Thanks to [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) for pointing out the ".value" argument that spares one further reshape. The [documentation](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) states that `.value` "tells pivot_longer() that that part of the column name specifies the “value” being measured (which will become a variable in the output)." While I don't fully grasp the documentation explanation, the results are that the matching regex are mapped to the variable names in the output data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3),
                  sex = c("M","F","M"),
                  day0mt = c(21,25,15),
                  day1mt = c(20,30,18),
                  day2mt = c(18,18,17),
                  day0ht = c(2,5,7),
                  day1ht = c(3,6,5),
                  day2ht = c(3,8,7))

df1
#>   id sex day0mt day1mt day2mt day0ht day1ht day2ht
#> 1  1   M     21     20     18      2      3      3
#> 2  2   F     25     30     18      5      6      8
#> 3  3   M     15     18     17      7      5      7

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("day"),
               names_pattern = "day(\\d+)(\\w+)",
               names_to = c("day", ".value"))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>      id sex   day      mt    ht
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1 M     0        21     2
#> 2     1 M     1        20     3
#> 3     1 M     2        18     3
#> 4     2 F     0        25     5
#> 5     2 F     1        30     6
#> 6     2 F     2        18     8
#> 7     3 M     0        15     7
#> 8     3 M     1        18     5
#> 9     3 M     2        17     7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Note that in newer versions of tidyr, `gather` and `spread` are deprecated and replaced by `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider.`

Comment: Use `names_to = c("day", ".value")` and remove the `pivot_wider` :-)

Comment: Thank you, this worked like a charm and I was able to modify the naming convention to my actual variables.

Comment: great! glad it worked. Thanks to r2evans for pointing out the ".value" special value. Now I'm finally happy with this solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest development-version of `data.table` (1.14.1) which adds some cool new melt-features..

use `data.table::update.dev.pkg()` for installation of the dev-version

```
library(data.table)
# data.table 1.14.1 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2021-06-22 09:38:23 UTC
dcast(
  melt(setDT(df1), measure.vars = measure(day, type, pattern="^day(.)(.)")),
  ... ~ type, value.var = "value")  

   id sex day  s t
1:  1   M   0 21 2
2:  1   M   1 20 3
3:  1   M   2 18 3
4:  2   F   0 25 5
5:  2   F   1 30 6
6:  2   F   2 18 8
7:  3   M   0 15 7
8:  3   M   1 18 5
9:  3   M   2 17 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. It first reshapes to long format, separates the `day*` column into day number and suffix columns and reshapes back to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("day")) %>%
  mutate(day = str_extract(name, "\\d+"),
         suffix = str_extract(name, "[^[:digit:]]+$")) %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = -c(value, suffix),
    names_from = suffix,
    values_from = value
  )
## A tibble: 9 x 5
#     id sex   day       s     t
#  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 M     0        21     2
#2     1 M     1        20     3
#3     1 M     2        18     3
#4     2 F     0        25     5
#5     2 F     1        30     6
#6     2 F     2        18     8
#7     3 M     0        15     7
#8     3 M     1        18     5
#9     3 M     2        17     7
```