# transform data from wide to long in r

Tags: r, pivot, reshape, melt, long-format-data

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
id_male<-rep(c(1:100),times=1)
df1<-data.frame(id_male)
df1$id_female <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id_male), replace=TRUE)
df1$var_ma_1 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$var_ma_2 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$var_ma_3 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$var_ma_4 <- sample(500:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$diff_1 <- sample(900:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$diff_2 <- sample(800:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$diff_3 <- sample(100:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$diff_4 <- sample(200:1000, length(df1$id_male))
df1$var <- sample(0:1, length(df1$id_male), replace=TRUE)

 id_male id_female var_ma_1 var_ma_2 var_ma_3 var_ma_4 diff_1 diff_2 diff_3 diff_4 var
       1       522      839      996      866      661    904    888    333    701   1
       2       548      706      967      855      682    974    838    257    572   0
       3       799      580      903      671      636    911    889    104    225   1
       4       518      745      565      719      707    959    983    465    239   0
       5       769      719      760      951      687    943    997    474    562   0
       6       745      642     1000      926      659    950    859    168    849   0
```

and I wanted to reshape this data to a long format:

```
id_male id_female visit var_ma  diff    var
  1        522      1     839    904     1
  1        522      2     996    888     1
  1        522      3     866    333     1
  1        522      4     661    701     1
  2        548      1     967    974     0
  2        548      2     855    838     0
  2        548      3     682    257     0
  2        548      4     947    572     0
```

I tried pivot_wider, reshape, and melt, but can't get it exactly what I want. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: @jpsmith I agree that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272) is a good reference, but I don't think it completely addresses the `names_pattern` component of this question. I'm confident there's another answer somewhere on SO that _does_, though, I just don't have it handy ...

Comment: @r2evans great point, I agree. Excellent answer

Comment: Related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058000/transforming-wide-data-to-long-format-with-multiple-variables)

Comment: That's it, @MartinGal, thank you for finding a good one.

Comment: llxx2021, I closed it since it is a dupe, but provided the answer while looking. If my answer (and the dupe-link) do not fully address your issue, please @ping me and we can discuss more details. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since part of some column names are kept as columns and part as a value in a new column, I think we can use `names_pattern` to separate out the number from the column name to form `visit`, and keep the rest.

```r
tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, -c(id_male, id_female, var),
  names_pattern = "(.*)_([0-9]+)$",
  names_to = c(".value", "visit"))
# # A tibble: 24 x 6
#    id_male id_female   var visit var_ma  diff
#      <int>     <int> <int> <chr>  <int> <int>
#  1       1       522     1 1        839   904
#  2       1       522     1 2        996   888
#  3       1       522     1 3        866   333
#  4       1       522     1 4        661   701
#  5       2       548     0 1        706   974
#  6       2       548     0 2        967   838
#  7       2       548     0 3        855   257
#  8       2       548     0 4        682   572
#  9       3       799     1 1        580   911
# 10       3       799     1 2        903   889
# # ... with 14 more rows
```

If you're unfamiliar with regex,

```
(.*)_([0-9]+)$
 ^^             0 or more of anything
^^^^            parens capture this as the first "group"
    ^           the literal underscore character
      ^^^^^^    1 or more digit (0-9 only)
     ^^^^^^^^   parens capture this as the second "group"
             ^  end of string
```

The two "groups" correspond to the `names_to` argument.

---

Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(id_male = 1:6, id_female = c(522L, 548L, 799L, 518L, 769L, 745L), var_ma_1 = c(839L, 706L, 580L, 745L, 719L, 642L), var_ma_2 = c(996L, 967L, 903L, 565L, 760L, 1000L), var_ma_3 = c(866L, 855L, 671L, 719L, 951L, 926L), var_ma_4 = c(661L, 682L, 636L, 707L, 687L, 659L), diff_1 = c(904L, 974L, 911L, 959L, 943L, 950L), diff_2 = c(888L, 838L, 889L, 983L, 997L, 859L), diff_3 = c(333L, 257L, 104L, 465L, 474L, 168L), diff_4 = c(701L, 572L, 225L, 239L, 562L, 849L), var = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,  0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```