# Hi! Is there a way to rename multiple columns (these columns are in numeric form) using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

As you can see columns are having both numbers and characters. How can we rename these using dplyr?

[image]

Comment: Generally it can be done using `dplyr::rename` or `dplyr::rename_with`.

Comment: Your column names look like years, so I think that you may want to get rid of the X in the names, However, column names are not permitted to start with a digit. see `help(make.names)`

Comment: What do you want the new names to be? If you really want years as column names, and assuming you use something like `read.csv` to get the data, one option is the argument `read.csv(..., check.names = FALSE)`, which will preserve the years. This also looks like data you would want to reshape to long format with one "year" column.

Comment: I really want to use dplyr and select columns starting with "X..and then rename them  by removing X and preserving rest of the column name.

Comment: (1) "year" in the column name violates a "soft" rule of mine: never have data (values) in a row or column name. It's "soft" because sometimes it just makes sense, but when I see something like this the first thing I tend to do is pivot/reshape the data from wide to long (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272). (2) Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/).