# Override legend for linechart with points

Tags: r, ggplot2

My current legend displays the shapes of the points in the chart, crossed out by the line. Id like to remove this line in the legend and just display the shapes.

The code looks like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data=cumdf, aes(x=quarters2)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_cumsum, colour='Platform participants'), size = 1.5)+
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_cumsum, colour='Platform participants', shape='Platform participants'), size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_interventions, colour='Actions'), size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_interventions, colour='Actions', shape='Actions'), size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = mean_sales, colour="Adopters"), size=1.5) +
  geom_point(aes(y = mean_sales, colour='Adopters', shape='Adopters'), size=3) +
  xlab("Quarters") +
  ylab("Cumulative occurences") +
  scale_shape_manual("", values=c("Platform participants" = 16, "Actions" = 17, "Adopters"=15)) +
  scale_colour_manual("",breaks = c("Platform participants", "Actions", "Adopters"),
                      values = c ("#C80000", "#696969", "#4E33FF")) +
  theme_stata(base_size = 15, base_family = "sans", scheme = "s2color") +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=14) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=3, linetype='dashed', size=1.7)
p
```

[image: Plot output]

Comment: Try with adding `show.legend=FALSE` to your `geom_line`s, i.e. `geom_line(..., show.legend = FALSE)`

Comment: In that case I would suggest to provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data.

Comment: I didn't read the comments before posting the answer (which implemented stefan's recommendation). The code works using _my_ data. Since it doesn't work with yours, it behooves you to make a sample of your data available, and/or clearly show where it doesn't work with your code. FYI, you'd need to do it with all `geom_line` calls, not just one, in case that's what you tried.)

Comment: I re-did it again but now for all lines, and it worked, thanks! I will update the post.

Comment: Further, your use of multiple `geom_line`/`geom_point` calls just because you add different `y=` mappings suggest that you can reduce your code by reshaping it (from wide-to-long, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272) and do just one call to each line/point. I'm happy to demonstrate this if you post sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Add `show.legend` to your `geom_line`. Since you have multiple calls to `geom_line`, you need to add it to *all* of them.

I'll demonstrate using `mtcars`, updated for a factor.

```r
dat <- transform(mtcars, cyl = factor(cyl))
```

Before the change:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(mpg, disp, group = cyl, color = cyl, shape = cyl)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2, legend has both lines and shapes]

Add `show.legend=FALSE`:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(mpg, disp, group = cyl, color = cyl, shape = cyl)) +
  geom_line(show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: ggplot2, legend only shows shapes]

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found in the comments, by adding `show.legend=FALSE` to `geom.line()` .