# Plotting via ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this dataset with 4 key features and the aim is to plot them in a single plot so I can analyze them simultaneously but I couldn't be able to achieve the goal. Can please someone guide me?

Sample Data:

```
dput(head(Mafraq.spi, 30))
structure(list(year = c(1985, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 
1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 
1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 
1988), `SPI 3` = c(1.03, 1.84, 0.06, -0.48, -0.05, 1.4, 1.4, 
0.74, 2.69, 1.79, 1.3, -0.59, -1.11, -1.14, -2.89, -1.4, -0.38, 
1.4, 1.4, 2.17, 0.67, 0.71, 0.03, -0.01, -0.02, 0.26, 0.69, 0.33, 
-0.38, 1.4), `SPI 6` = c(0.32, 0.24, 0.52, 0.91, 1.8, 0.05, -0.53, 
0.46, 2.68, 1.78, 1.29, 1.28, 0.87, 0.67, -1.53, -1.83, -1.33, 
-2.9, -1.4, 1.89, 0.66, 0.7, 0.46, 0.19, 0.38, 0.05, 0.21, -0.09, 
0.11, 0.68), `SPI 9` = c(0.32, 0.17, 0.15, 0.15, 0.21, 0.52, 
0.9, 1.87, 2.63, 1.76, 1.28, 1.27, 0.86, 0.7, 0.65, 0.65, 0.61, 
-1.54, -1.87, -0.32, -1.08, 0.38, 0.39, 0.19, 0.37, 0.41, 0.35, 
0.35, -0.02, 0.21), `SPI 12` = c(0.24, 0.14, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 
0.15, 0.15, 0.27, 1.91, 1.93, 1.87, 1.19, 0.75, 0.69, 0.64, 0.64, 
0.64, 0.64, 0.65, 0.94, -1.1, -0.62, -0.23, -0.54, 0.15, 0.35, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(1:11, names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"), class = "omit"))
```

Code:

```
library(dplyr)

Mafraq.spi <- na.omit(read_excel("K:/talha.R/Project 56/Mafraq-his-SPI-SPEI.xlsx", sheet = "SPI"))
selected_vars <- c("year", "SPI 3", "SPI 6", "SPI 9", "SPI 12")
Mafraq.spi <- Mafraq.spi %>%
  select(all_of(selected_vars)) %>%
  mutate(year = as.Date(paste0(year, "-01-01")))

ggplot(Mafraq.spi, aes(x = year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `SPI 12`, color = "SPI 12")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `SPI 9`, color = "SPI 9")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `SPI 6`, color = "SPI 6")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = `SPI 3`, color = "SPI 3")) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Value", color = "Variable") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SPI 12" = "blue", "SPI 9" = "red", "SPI 6" = "green", "SPI 3" = "purple")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

My Plot:
[image]

What I wanted:
[image]

Fix with the help of @r2evans:

```
Mafraq.spi %>%
  mutate(year = year + (row_number() - 1)/12) %>%
  mutate(year = ifelse(year == 1985, 1985 + 11/12, year)) %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("SPI"), names_to = "SPI", values_to = "value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = SPI)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(SPI ~ .) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SPI 12" = "blue", "SPI 9" = "red", "SPI 6" = "green", "SPI 3" = "purple")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Plot: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `facet_grid` breaks it into individual "swim lanes" or panels.
2. I'm *inferring* that since you have twelve observations for two of the years in the sample that the rows are monthly, in which case we can adjust `year` to be fractional.
3. This will be easier if we reshape the data from wide to long (see [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272), [Transforming wide data to long format with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272)). For one, it means we can issue a single `geom` for all of the different `SPI` levels.

Adjusted code:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_longer
library(ggplot2)
Mafraq.spi %>%
  mutate(year = year + (row_number() - 1)/12, .by = year) %>%
  # very special case with this sample data so that 1985 starts at
  # the last month of the year; this may only be useful for this sample
  # data, be careful with "real" data
  mutate(year = if_else(year == 1985, 1985 + 11/12, year)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "SPI") %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = SPI)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(SPI ~ .) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("SPI 12" = "blue", "SPI 9" = "red", "SPI 6" = "green", "SPI 3" = "purple")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: ggplot]

Options:

- if you don't want the legend, add `scale_color_manual(guide="none", ...)`;
- alternatively, since the lines are broken out into facets, you may not *need* different colors for each `SPI`; and
- if you want the facets to say `"6 months"` instead of `"SPI 6"` then you can add `mutate(SPI = paste(sub("SPI ", "", SPI), "months"))` after the pivot and then update the manual colors in your `scale_color_manual` values.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance but getting this error `Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `year = if_else(year == 1985, 1985 + 11/12, year)`.
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must have class `numeric`, not class `Date`.`

Comment: That means your sample data is different from your real data. It's an easy fix: make sure `year` is numeric by doing `mutate(year = as.numeric(year))` earlier in the pipe. (You _could_ switch to `ifelse` instead, since it is class-unsafe and will do what we intend here.) (Odd, though ... this should have been done if you did `year + (row_number() - 1)/12`, so it suggests you're taking part of my code, not all of it. Is my assumption about `year` incorrect?)

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question with a fix but got a different plot. The distribution of the data is not smoothed as yours. Please have a look @r2evans

Comment: Your `year` appears to be not what I inferred it to be. Please clarify _exactly_ what `year` is intended to be. The fact that your x-axis now spans to 15000 says that my "month" assumption is not correct.

Comment: The correct timeline of the original data is from 1985 to 2021.

Comment: You need to use ALL of the code in my answer. If your version of dplyr is before 1.1, then you need to change `mutate(year = year + (row_number() - 1)/12, .by = year)` to `group_by(year) %>% mutate(year = year + (row_number() - 1)/12)`. You cannot take _part_ of an answer code, discard the rest, and assume that it will work as expected in the provided answer.