# Overlay line plot over bar plot with multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, overlay, linechart

I am trying to create a bar plot with 1 set of data, and a line plot overlaid on top with another set of data.

I can create the plots separate no problem, but can't combine them. See bar plot code below:

```
bar = read.csv("bar.csv", header = TRUE)
bar2 = df %>% 
  gather(desc, value, c(-Station, -Treatment)) %>% 
  separate(desc, c("Stat", "Var")) %>% 
  spread(Stat, value)

xx = ggplot(bar2, aes(x = Var, y = Avg, ymin = Avg-Std, ymax = Avg+Std)) 
+ facet_wrap(~Station) 
+ geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.65) 
+ geom_errorbar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.65), width = 0.4) + theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))

xx
```

And then the line plot:

```
line = read.csv("line.csv", header = TRUE)
line2 = line %>% 
      gather(desc, value, c(-Station, -HC, -Treatment)) %>% 
      separate(desc, c("Stat", "Var")) %>% 
      spread(Stat, value)

xx + geom_line(hc2, aes(x=Var, y=Avg), colour = HC) + facet_wrap(~Station)
```

Where I would like there to be 2 coloured lines showing the different HC variables. When I go to add the line plot I keep getting this error:

```
Error in list2(na.rm = na.rm, orientation = orientation, ...) : 
  object 'HC' not found
```

Here is what my data looks like:

[image: bar2]
[image: line2]

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Comment: `gather` and `spread` have been superseded (or retired) for well over 4 years, recommending a shift to `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`, I think you'll find those newer functions more powerful and perhaps understood by more people these days. I wonder if your `gather` is to blame. But to complicate it all ... you show images of `bar2` and `line2`, we do not see `bar`, and you never define `df`, suggesting your code has patches from different interactive sessions.

Comment: Please make this question more reproducible by including usable sample data (from `dput`, `data.frame`, or `read.table`, preferably), consistent code, and your expected output. It really helps when you have verified the code in a new (fresh!) session to make sure you have not missed objects (such as `df` above). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269 , [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for good discussions on sample data/code/packages, etc.

Comment: hi @r2evans thank you for the advice and apologies for my lack of clarity. I did not realize 'gather' and 'spread' were outdated. I am having trouble getting the same dataframe (from bar > bar2) using pivot_longer/pivot_wider.. do you recommend I make a new question for this?

Comment: Usable sample data, please. I know nothing about `df` at all, and I'm not going to try to transcribe images. For pivoting/reshaping, I really like these links: **long-to-wide**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5890584/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/11608167/3358272; **wide-to-long**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272

Comment: hi @r2evans thank you for the advice. I will go back and do so. apologies I am still new to the stack etiquette. I will be deleting this question and and reposting with reproducible examples once I figure out how to do so... thanks.

Comment: You don't need to delete, you can [edit] it in place, but over to you.