# Boxplot in log scale (how do I keep the original values on y-axis?)

Tags: r, graphics, boxplot, axis

I'd like some help with R. I have a dataset represented as a matrix with 40 rows and 12 columns. I need the boxplot of these data in logarithmic scale.

I use the following command:

```r
boxplot(log(data[,2:13]))
```

And I get the graph as desired, but I'd like the values of the Y axis to be the original values, that is, referring to the data not transformed into log. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll start with some sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
data <- data.frame(lapply(setNames(nm=letters[1:4]), function(ign) runif(100, 1, 10)))
head(data)
#          a        b        c        d
# 1 9.233254 6.636208 8.966059 5.353913
# 2 9.433679 2.954419 5.653999 5.001126
# 3 3.575256 2.949106 8.667379 1.543470
# 4 8.474029 4.500505 4.985166 3.947554
# 5 6.775710 9.482101 2.420921 8.905861
# 6 5.671864 9.663472 4.980922 9.375444
```

The docs for [`boxplot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html) includes

> *named arguments are arguments and graphical parameters to be passed to `bxp` ...*

which, while not clear on what is available, does suggest one read [`bxp`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/bxp.html), which includes:

```
          Currently, ‘yaxs’ and ‘ylim’ are used ‘along the boxplot’,
          i.e., vertically, when ‘horizontal’ is false, and ‘xlim’
          horizontally.  ‘xaxt’, ‘yaxt’, ‘las’, ‘cex.axis’, ‘gap.axis’,
          and ‘col.axis’ are passed to axis, and ‘main’, ‘cex.main’,
          ‘col.main’, ‘sub’, ‘cex.sub’, ‘col.sub’, ‘xlab’, ‘ylab’,
          ‘cex.lab’, and ‘col.lab’ are passed to title.
```

Unfortunately, we can't control the y-axis much more with this, so we use `yaxt="n"` to suppress the automatic formatting of the y axis (see [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) and read about `"xaxt"` and `"yaxt"`). From there, we can use `axis(...)` ourselves.

```r
boxplot(log(data[,2:4]), yaxt = "n")
axis(2, at = axTicks(2), labels = round(exp(axTicks(2)), 2), las = 1)
```

[image: base plot with un-logged y-axis labels]

One might argue that the decimal axis ticks is not ideal, we can also bring in `axisTicks`:

```r
boxplot(log(data[,2:4]), yaxt = "n")
ax <- axisTicks(exp(par("usr")[3:4]), log = FALSE)
axis(2, at = log(ax), labels = ax, las = 1)
```

[image: base plot, log axis, better labels]

---

As an aside, one could also use `ggplot2`, though it is very different from base graphics. First of all, it really benefits from "long" data, namely changing from the "wide" form of this `data` to

```r
datalong <- reshape2::melt(data, id.vars=c())
head(datalong,3); tail(datalong,3)
#   variable    value
# 1        a 9.233254
# 2        a 9.433679
# 3        a 3.575256
#     variable    value
# 398        d 9.162482
# 399        d 5.961255
# 400        d 1.680392
```

For this, we can have some fun:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(datalong, aes(variable, value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_trans(y = "log")
```

[image: ggplot boxplot]

(Oops, I didn't continue my example of omitting the first column ... which was really only useful to try to remain consistent with your original code. FYI, if you want/need help in this `reshape2::melt` operation, I suggest you visit [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2185252/3358272), [Transforming wide data to long format with multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68058000/3358272). There are countless references, Q/As, and other places to learn about `ggplot2`; I often use https://r-graph-gallery.com for good examples.)

Comment: there is also `boxplot(data, log="y")`

Comment: Sure, but who wants to do it the *easy* way? :-)